# using a template within joomla gives fatal error

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I am trying to use a template within Joomla 3.0. I installed the template on Joomla and I tried to use the preview button to see it. however I got this errors.

`( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function mosShowListMenu()`, beside this I also get 3 other warning such as:

```
Warning: include_once(C:\wamp\www\HAMED\templates\jf_texturiaDS/scripts/php/mainmenu.php)

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:\wamp\www\HAMED\templates\jf_texturiaDS/scripts/php/mainmenu.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
```

Does any one know where are these errors coming from and how I can fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mos` prefix indicates it dates from the Joomla! 1.0/1.5 error so it may not be compatible, but it's more likely that you're using a template that is dependent on extensions and modules by the template creator.

A quick Google search shows this results at [BlueStone Design](http://www.bluestonedesign.de/faq/11-webdesign/101--fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mosshowlistmenu-), which translates to:

> After installing a new template for Joomla appears the error `Fatal
>   error: Call to undefined function mosShowListMenu () on.`
>
> This can have several reasons:
>
> 1. Some essential modules are not yet activated. In the backend just activate all modules.
> 2. Some essential modules are not installed yet. In the downloaded archive again see if maybe a folder hidden in the plug-ins or modules that need will still be installed.
> 3. Wrong Joomla version. Perhaps the template is version dependent. Enable legacy mode to test project.

***Note*** the reference to "Legacy Mode" this is a Joomla! 1.5 plug-in to help support old 1.0 compatible templates and extensions...

Answer (score 1):

Hello are you sure that your template is build for Joomla 3.0 ?, also check for your templates component or modules.